# Page numbers in Table of contents should be aligned left

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, tocloft, titletoc

I'm writing my thesis, but unfortunately I'm having a problem. In our thesis template, the page numbers in table of contents should be aligned left (default=right) as shown in the figure. When I look for the solution of it, I learned that `tocloft` package allows that by using `\renewcommand{\cftpnumalign}{l}`.

But it gives an error as

```
"! LaTeX Error: \cftpnumalign undefined."
```

I don't know how can I fix. Is there an easy solution of the problem?

Thank you in advance. !!

[image]

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{section}
[0.0em]
{}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace{\hspace*{-0.2em}}}
{}
{\titlerule*[0.25pc]{.}\contentspage}


\titlecontents{subsection}
[1.6em]
{}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace{\hspace*{-0.2em}}}
{}
{\titlerule*[0.25pc]{.}\contentspage}


\titlecontents{subsubsection}
[1.6em]
{}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace{\hspace*{-0.2em}}}
{}
{\titlerule*[0.25pc]{.}\contentspage}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{1ex}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3ex}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{1pt}

\renewcommand{\cftpnumalign}{l} 

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{one}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{25}
\subsection{two}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{9}
\section{three}


\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{9}
\section{four}


\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{1}
\subsection{five}


\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{one}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{25}
\subsection{two}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{259}
\section{three}


\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{8699}
\section{four}


\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{1}
\subsection{five}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As given, your MWE doesn't show the error you're describing.

Comment: Also, an alternative preamble with only `\usepackage{tocloft} \renewcommand{\cftpnumalign}{l}` in a simple document with a single table of contents and both roman and arabic page numbering does show left-aligned numbers.

Comment: `titletoc` and `tocloft` aren't compatible, in my point of view. Removing `titletoc` will provide the left aligned page numbers

Comment: thank you for the update. I tried what you said, but unfortunately it again gave the same error.

Comment: yes, it is latest version. Did you mean adding the error message in logfile. That is like in the following.  { "*File List*
article.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
tocloft.sty 2010/10/13 v2.3e parameterised ToC, etc., typesetting
titletoc.sty 2011/12/15 v1.6 TOC entries"}  is it correct ? or else.

Comment: Actualy, I  would like to learn whether there is any way to align left the page numbers of Table of contents in article class.

Comment: There is always a way.   You simply have to replace the existing code (which depends on what packages are being used).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix the use of two ToC-related packages.

That's why any adjustment to `\cftpnumalign` doesn't show in the ToC, since [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) has completely rewritten the way ToC-related entries are handled.

The following is all that's needed to change the alignment (and width):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\contentspage}[1][\thecontentspage]{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{#1\hfil}\hspace*{-\@pnumwidth}}
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
\makeatother
```

The first adjustment is made to `\contentspage` in order to change the alignment from `r`ight (default) to `l`eft. The second changes the width of the page setting to `3em` (default is 15pt).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{section}
  [0.0em]
  {}
  {\thecontentslabel.\enspace{\hspace*{-0.2em}}}
  {}
  {\titlerule*[0.25pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}
  [1.6em]
  {}
  {\thecontentslabel.\enspace{\hspace*{-0.2em}}}
  {}
  {\titlerule*[0.25pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}
  [1.6em]
  {}
  {\thecontentslabel.\enspace{\hspace*{-0.2em}}}
  {}
  {\titlerule*[0.25pc]{.}\contentspage}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\contentspage}[1][\thecontentspage]{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{#1\hfil}\hspace*{-\@pnumwidth}}
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{one}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{25}
\subsection{two}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{9}
\section{three}


\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{9}
\section{four}


\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{1}
\subsection{five}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{one}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{25}
\subsection{two}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{259}
\section{three}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{8699}
\section{four}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{1}
\subsection{five}

\end{document}
```

<sub>The frame is provided by [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe).</sub>

Comment: It is working, great thanks. I spent too much time to solve it. That is nice to see.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about tocloft or titletoc, but for plain old article class...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\def\@pnumwidth{.5in}% maximum width for number on right

\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{#2\hss}}\par% left align
       \nobreak
       \if@compatibility
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
      \fi
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{#2\hss}\par% left align
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
 \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
 \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
 {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
 \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
 \interlinepenalty\@M
 \leavevmode
 \@tempdima #3\relax
 \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
 {#4}\nobreak
 \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
 \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
 mu$}\hfill
 \nobreak
 \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\normalfont \normalcolor #5\hfil}% left align
 \par}%
 \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{one}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{25}
\subsection{two}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{9}
\section{three}


\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{9}
\section{four}


\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{1}
\subsection{five}


\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newpage
\section{one}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{25}
\subsection{two}

\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{259}
\section{three}


\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{8699}
\section{four}


\newpage
\addtocounter{page}{1}
\subsection{five}


\end{document}
```